# method overloading in python

Tags: python, overloading

I need to call unparameterised method `first`, but also parameterized `first`, but it is giving an error.

```
>>> class A:
...     def first(self):
...             print 'first method'
...     def first(self,f):
...             print 'first met',f
...
>>> a=A()
>>> a.first()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: first() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Is it possible to do method overloading in Python like in Java?

Comment: *Please* inherit from object!  You don't *really* want an old-style class, do you?  (This would be a non-issue in Python 3, but your print statements tell me that you're using Python 2.)

Answer (score 13):

Your second `first` method is overriding the original `first` method. In Python, it is not possible to create overloaded methods the same way as in Java.

However, you can create methods with optional and/or keyword-based arguments and process those accordingly. Here's an example:

```
class A:
    def first(self, f=None):
        if f is not None:
            print 'first met', f
        else:
            print 'first method'
```

Usage:

```
a = A()
a.first()
a.first('something')
```

Comment: Yeah.  The default argument style of python is actually more concise, and, imo, easier to read and maintain then the Java-style giant list of overridden methods with decreasing numbers of arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Python doesn't do function overloading. This is a consequence of it being a loosely-typed language. Instead you can specify an unknown number of arguments and deal with their interpretation in the function logic.

There are a couple ways you can do this. You can specify specific optional arguments:

```
def func1(arg1, arg2=None):
    if arg2 != None:
        print "%s %s" % (arg1, arg2)
    else:
        print "%s" % (arg1)
```

Calling it we get:

```
>>> func1(1, 2)
1 2
```

Or you can specify an unknown number of unnamed arguments (i.e. arguments passed in an array):

```
def func2(arg1, *args):
    if args:
        for item in args:
            print item
    else:
        print arg1
```

Calling it we get:

```
>>> func2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
2
3
4
5
```

Or you can specify an unknown number of named arguments (i.e. arguments passed in a dictionary):

```
def func3(arg1, **args):
    if args:
        for k, v in args.items():
            print "%s %s" % (k, v)
    else:
        print arg1
```

Calling it we get:

```
>>> func3(1, arg2=2, arg3=3)
arg2 2
arg3 3
```

You can use these constructions to produce the behaviour you were looking for in overloading.

Comment: Your `func1()` doesn't behave as a called might expect when it's called as `func1(1, 0)`

Answer (score 6):

Usually you can only define one method in a class with a given name. In your example the 2 argument first() method overwrote the 1 argument first(). If you want two methods with the same name, in python 3 you have to use functools.singledispatch, and map the instance method name to your static method dispatcher, Ouch!

That said, I really like *implicit* dynamic dispatch in OO programming, and I find it cleaner than writing manual dispatch logic in some kind of  'master' first() function, which is repetitive and brittle to extension.

Challenge question: add another method like A.first(A arg).

You'll probably learn a lot about the python type system if you try to do this!

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python3.4

from functools import singledispatch;

class A(object):

    # default method handles dispatch for undefined types
    # note reversed positional args to match single dispatch functools
    @singledispatch
    def _first(self,arg):
        raise TypeError("no match for A._first(%s)" % type(arg));

    # adapter maps instance call to (reversed) static method call
    def first(self, arg = None): return A._first(arg, self);

    # def first()
    @_first.register(type(None))
    def _(self,none):
        print("A.first() called");

    # def first(float f)
    @_first.register(float)
    def _(self,f):
        print("A.first(float %s) called" % f);

a = A();
a.first();              # A.first() called
a.first(None);          # A.first() called
a.first(3.14);          # A.first(float 3.14) called

class B(object): pass;
b = B();                
try: a.first(b);        # no match for A._first(<class '__main__.B'>)
except TypeError as ex: print(ex);
```

Comment: Oh, that's *clever* :-)

Answer (score 0):

Python is not C++ or Java; you can't overload methods in the same way.

Really, the only way to do what you want is to test for the presence or absence of the second parameter:

```
class A:
   def first(self, f=None):
      if f is None:
         print 'first method'
      else:
         print 'first met',f
```

You can be yet more sophisticated and check the type of `f` but that can be dangerous, and is not always "pythonic". (However, it should be mentioned that one use case for [function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) in Python 3 is to allow this sort of "Generic Programming".)

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to create a system that appears to use overloaded methods, it's a bit involved, and not usually needed.

The usual idiom is to have possibly unneeded parameters default to `None`, like so:

```
class A:
    def first(self, f=None):
        if f is None:
            print 'first method'
        else:
            print 'first met',f
```

In your case, where you want different behavior based upon whether or not this is the first call to that method, this is what I would do:

```
class A:
    def first(self):
        print 'first method'
        self.first = self._first
    def _first(self, f):                   # '_' is convention for private name
        print 'first met',f
```

and sample output:

```
a = A()
a.first()
a.first(3)
```

prints:

```
first method
first met 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code if it is helpful:

```
from math import pi

class Geometry:

    def area(self,length = None,breadth = None,side = None,radius = None):
        self.length = length
        self.breadth = breadth
        self.side = side
        self.radius = radius

        if length != None and breadth != None:
            return length * breadth
        elif side != None:
            return side * side
        else:
            return pi * radius * radius

obj1 = Geometry()
print('Area of rectangle is {0}.'.format(obj1.area(length=5,breadth=4)))
print('Area of square is {0}.'.format(obj1.area(side=5)))
print('Area of circle is {0:.6}.'.format(obj1.area(radius=10)))
```

Comment: The question is about method overloading in python.