# python - How the overloading methods get loaded

Tags: python, constructor

Questions:

1. Does python load the methods the way - who comes last who wins? Even if you have two methods share the exact name, even with different arguments(different signatures), the last one will overrule all the previous ones anyway without giving runtime error?
2. If python has no overloading, what's the python recommended way to do overloading like JAVA?

the example below:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Base created without args"
    def __init__(self, a):
        print "Base created " + a + "\n"
```

`print Base("test")` gives me:

```
Base created test

<__main__.Base object at 0x1090fff10>
```

While `print Base()` gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "${path to super file}/super.py", line 27, in <module>
print Base()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [method overloading in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725968/method-overloading-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Basically, you already answered that question yourself. Python does not care about the method signature, only the name is significant. This applies to module-level functions, too.
2. Unlike Java, Python allows you to specify default values for method arguments (which in my opinion is far more convenient):

   ```
   class Base(object):
       def __init__(self, a=None):
           if a is None:
               print "Base created without args."
           else:
               print "Base created with %s" % a

   a = Base()    # prints "Base created without args."
   b = Base(123) # prints "Base created with 123."
   ```

Comment: Additionally, duck-typing removes the need for method overloading in most other scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own method overloader using decorators:

```
class OverloadFunction(object):

    def __new__(cls, f):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        setattr(self, "_dct", {})
        return self.overload(())(f)

    def overload(self, signature):
        def wrapper(f):
            self._dct[signature] = f
            return self
        return wrapper

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._dct[self._get_signature(args)](*args, **kwargs)

    def _get_signature(self, obj):
        return tuple(type(x) for x in obj)


@OverloadFunction
def hello():
    print "hello, no args"

@hello.overload((int,))
def hello(i):
    print "hello with an int argument:", i

@OverloadFunction
def add(): pass

@add.overload((int, int))
def add(a, b):
    print "integer addition, %d + %d = %d" % (a, b, a + b)

@add.overload((str, int))
def add(a, b):
    print "string concatentation, %r + %d = %r" % (a, b, a + str(b))

hello()
hello(1)
add(2, 3)
add("a", 3)
```

Which outputs:

```
hello, no args
hello with an int argument: 1
integer addition, 2 + 3 = 5
string concatentation, 'a' + 3 = 'a3'
```

Comment: Although, as [helmbert said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15486148/1142167), you should probably just use default arguments instead.