# How to write __getitem__ cleanly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, when implementing a sequence type, I often (relatively speaking) find myself writing code like this:

```
class FooSequence(collections.abc.Sequence):
    # Snip other methods

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            # Get a single item
        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            # Get a whole slice
        else:
            raise TypeError('Index must be int, not {}'.format(type(key).__name__))
```

The code checks the type of its argument explicitly with `isinstance()`.  This is [regarded as an antipattern](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/#rationale-and-goals) within the Python community.  How do I avoid it?

- I cannot use `functools.singledispatch`, because that's [quite deliberately](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-dev/122554/) incompatible with methods (it will attempt to dispatch on `self`, which is entirely useless since we're already dispatching on `self` via OOP polymorphism).  It works with `@staticmethod`, but what if I need to get stuff out of `self`?
- Casting to `int()` and then catching the `TypeError`, checking for a slice, and possibly re-raising is still ugly, though perhaps slightly less so.
- It might be cleaner to convert integers into one-element slices and handle both situations with the same code, but that has its own problems (return `0` or `[0]`?).

Comment: The antipattern is using `type()` instead of `isinstance()`, and using such code at the user-level -- when writing `__dunder__` methods you are expected to do type checks... using `isinstance()`.

Comment: As of 3.8, this question [is obsolete](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As much as it seems odd, I suspect that the way you have it is the best way to go about things. Patterns generally exist to encompass common use cases, but that doesn't mean that they should be taken as gospel when following them makes life more difficult. The main reason that PEP 443 gives for balking at explicit typechecking is that it is "brittle and closed to extension". However, that mainly applies to custom functions that take a number of different types at any time. From the [Python docs on `__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

> For sequence types, the accepted keys should be integers and slice objects. Note that the special interpretation of negative indexes (if the class wishes to emulate a sequence type) is up to the __getitem__() method. If key is of an inappropriate type, TypeError may be raised; if of a value outside the set of indexes for the sequence (after any special interpretation of negative values), IndexError should be raised. For mapping types, if key is missing (not in the container), KeyError should be raised.

The Python documentation explicitly states the two types that should be accepted, and what to do if an item that is not of those two types is provided. Given that the types are provided by the documentation itself, it's unlikely to change (doing so would break far more implementations than just yours), so it's likely not worth the trouble to go out of your way to code against Python itself potentially changing.

If you're set on avoiding explicit typechecking, I would point you toward [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24602374/1935092). It contains a concise implementation of a `@methdispatch` decorator (not my name, but i'll roll with it) that lets `@singledispatch` work with methods by forcing it to check `args[1]` (arg) rather than `args[0]` (self). Using that should allow you to use custom single dispatch with your `__getitem__` method.

Whether or not you consider either of these "pythonic" is up to you, but remember that while The Zen of Python notes that "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules", it then immediately notes that "practicality beats purity". In this case, just checking for the two types that the documentation explicitly states are the only things `__getitem__` should support seems like the practical way to me.

Answer (score 3):

The antipattern is for code to do explicit type checking, which means using the  `type()` function.  Why?  Because then a subclass of the target type will no longer work.  For instance, `__getitem__` can use an `int`, but using `type()` to check for it means an `int`-subclass, which would work, will fail only because `type()` does not return `int`.

When a type-check is necessary, `isinstance` is the appropriate way to do it as it does not exclude subclasses.

When writing `__dunder__` methods, type checking is necessary and expected -- using `isinstance()`.

In other words, your code is perfectly Pythonic, and its only problem is the error message (it doesn't mention `slice`s).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to avoid doing it *once*.  That's just the tradeoff of using a dynamically-typed language in this way.  However, that doesn't mean you have to do it over and over again.  I would solve it once by creating an abstract class with split out method names, then inherit from that class instead of directly from `Sequence`, like:

```
class UnannoyingSequence(collections.abc.Sequence):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return self.getitem(key)
        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            return self.getslice(key)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Index must be int, not {}'.format(type(key).__name__))

    # default implementation in terms of getitem
    def getslice(self, key):
        # Get a whole slice

class FooSequence(UnannoyingSequence):
    def getitem(self, key):
        # Get a single item

    # optional efficient, type-specific implementation not in terms of getitem
    def getslice(self, key):
        # Get a whole slice
```

This cleans up `FooSequence` enough that I might even do it this way if I only had the one derived class. I'm sort of surprised the standard library doesn't already work that way.

Comment: Of course, the language *used* to do this for us with `__getslice__`, but that's deprecated, which makes me wonder about the soundness of the entire technique.

Comment: @Kevin, it was deprecated for different reasons.  They wanted to create a `slice` object, but `__getslice__` took `i` and `j` arguments.  It would have broken backwards compatibility.

Answer (score -3):

To stay pythonic, you have work with the semantics rather than the type of the objects. So if you have some parameter as accessor to a sequence, just use it like that. Use the abstraction for a parameter as long as possible. If you expect a set of user identifiers, do not expect a set, but rather some data structure with a method `add`. If you expect some text, do not expect a `unicode` object, but rather some container for characters featuring `encode` and `decode` methods.

I assume in general you want to do something like "Use the behavior of the base implementation unless some special value is provided. If you want to implement `__getitem__`, you can use a case distinction where something different happens if one special value is provided. I'd use the following pattern:

```
class FooSequence(collections.abc.Sequence):
    # Snip other methods

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            if key == SPECIAL_VALUE:
                return SOMETHING_SPECIAL
            else:
                return self.our_baseclass_instance[key]
        except AttributeError:
            raise TypeError('Wrong type: {}'.format(type(key).__name__))
```

If you want to distinguish between a single value (in perl terminology "scalar") and a sequence (in Java terminology "collection"), then it is pythonically fine to determine whether an iterator is implemented. You can either use a try-catch pattern or `hasattr` as I do now:

```
>>> a = 42
>>> b = [1, 3, 5, 7]
>>> c = slice(1, 42)
>>> hasattr(a, "__iter__")
False
>>> hasattr(b, "__iter__")
True
>>> hasattr(c, "__iter__")
False
>>>
```

Applied to our example:

```
class FooSequence(collections.abc.Sequence):
    # Snip other methods

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            if hasattr(key, "__iter__"):
                return map(lambda x: WHATEVER(x), key)
            else:
                return self.our_baseclass_instance[key]
        except AttributeError:
            raise TypeError('Wrong type: {}'.format(type(key).__name__))
```

Dynamic programming languages like python and ruby use duck typing. And a duck is an animal, that walks like a duck, swims like a duck and quacks like a duck. Not because somebody calls it a "duck".

Comment: I would agree, but the documentation for getitem explicitly states "only allow int and slice type objects". There is no reason to allow or accept iterables for the simple reason that getitem isn't supposed to accept iterables, and for the purposes of the `[]` operator, a list will never be provided. Duck typing is all well and good, but the documentation is extremely explicit about exactly what items to accept. See [the python docs for getitem](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) for more info.

Comment: I don't have a base implementation.  I'm doing everything by hand.  The code has been simplified for expository purposes; my actual code is 3D-sliceable, does not use NumPy, and has to do a fair amount of index preprocessing which would otherwise be rather distracting.

Comment: In that case I consider @SevenDeadlySins's answer the most helpful one.