# Passing self object to function that requires this type

Tags: python, oop, overloading

I wanted to write a class function which takes Signal object as a parameter and returns its copy. Then I wanted to overload this function with an instance function that returns copy of self argument. I have a following code:

```
@classmethod
def copy(cls, arg):
    if not isinstance(arg, Signal):
        raise ValueError("Argument must be of type Signal")
    result = Signal()
    result.framerate = arg.framerate
    return result

def copy(self):
    return FragmentsSignal.copy(self)
```

and

```
Signal1 = Signal(100)
Signal2 = signal1.copy()
```

But after calling the function copy my code goes into infinite recursive loop and throws name of this site as an exception. My questions are:

1. Do I properly use python function overloading mechanism?
2. How can I pass *this argument to a class function within my class?

Comment: Is framerate the only Signal attribute? And do you want it to copy just one attribute (if there would be more in future) or all of them?

Comment: No, it isn't. I simplified code to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I properly use python function overloading mechanism?

You can't have two functions with the same name; Python does not support overloading based on the types of the arguments. The definition of the second function will override that of the first.

In essence you're calling the non `classmethod` function `copy` over and over again. You'll need to rename one of these in order to get it to work effectively.

> How can I pass *this argument to a class function within my class?

I'm guessing you mean `self` here; passing `self` to another function is done as with any other arg (as you did `FragmentsSignal.copy(self)`). Your issue is that you're getting stumped by the recursion caused by the similar names.

Comment: That's fair enough. Thank you :)

Comment: Technically you can support overloading via argument type, with [`functools.singledsipatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) (although it takes a little [work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24602374) to persuade it to do something useful with methods). But +1 anyway, since I'm being pedantic and your answer is the one OP needs :-)