# How to combine @singledispatch and @lru_cache?

Tags: python, annotations, generic-programming, lru, single-dispatch

I have a Python single-dispatch generic function like this:

```
@singledispatch
def cluster(documents, n_clusters=8, min_docs=None, depth=2):
  ...
```

It is overloaded like this:

```
@cluster.register(QuerySet)
@lru_cache(maxsize=512)
def _(documents, *args, **kwargs):
  ...
```

The second one basically preprocesses a `QuerySet` object and calls the generic `cluster()` function.
A [QuerySet is a Django object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/), but that should not play a role here; apart from the fact that it is hashable and thus usable with `lru_cache`.

The generic function cannot be cached though because it accepts unhashable objects such as lists as arguments. However, the overloading function can be cached because a `QuerySet` object is hashable. That is why I've added the `@lru_cache()` annotation.

However, caching does not seem to be applied:

```
qs: QuerySet = [...]

start = datetime.now(); cluster(Document.objects.all()); print(datetime.now() - start)               
0:00:02.629259
```

I would expect the same call to take place in an instance, but:

```
start = datetime.now(); cluster(Document.objects.all()); print(datetime.now() - start)               
0:00:02.468675
```

This is confirmed by the cache statistics:

```
cluster.registry[django.db.models.query.QuerySet].cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=2, maxsize=512, currsize=2)
```

Changing the order of the `@lru_cache` and the `@.register` annotations does not seem to make a difference.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599852/lru-cache-interferes-with-type-checking-done-by-single-dispatch) is similar, but the answer does not fit on the individual function level.

Is it even possible to combine these two annotations on this level? If so, how?

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating your issue with simpler types.  I'm on Python 3.7.  When the `@cluster.register` is first then it works as you expect.  When the `@lru_cache` is first it doesn't seem to work.  I would check that your repeated calls to `Document.objects.all()` return equal objects.  I think a better test would be calling `cluster` on `qs` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hash(Document.objects.all()) == hash(Document.objects.all())` is not consistent for Django `QuerySet`.

The call `Document.objects.all()` doesn't hit the database until the `QuerySet` returned is evaluated.

> Pickling is usually used as a precursor to caching

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets).

Depending on your use case you can try caching the pickle of the `QuerySet` or its `query` attribute.

```
@cluster.register(bytes)
@lru_cache(maxsize=512)
def _(documents, *args, **kwargs):
    documents = pickle.loads(documents)
    ...

cluster(pickle.dumps(Document.objects.all()))
```

or

```
cluster(pickle.dumps(Document.objects.all().query))
```